# Outlook. Стандартизированная подпись у всех пользователей в домене

Tags: powershell, office, outlook

Хочу всем пользователям в домене сделать стандартизированную подпись в Outlook.
Нужно, чтобы каждому новому сотруднику не приходилось вручную вбивать себе подпись, а чтобы все подтягивалось автоматически из AD.

Нашел этот древний гайдик (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2006.10.heyscriptingguy.aspx), там во 2 пункте расписано, как сделать скрипт для работы с AD, но вот незадача, я крайне не силен в этих скриптах, а у нас в подписи есть стандартизированный текст и картинка.

В теории сам текст можно вписать в переменную скрипта, а вот что делать с картинкой я ума не приложу. Может кто подсказать или может у кого есть другое решение? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Про картинки не знаю, но гайд тут https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm

Comment: Спасибо за гайдик! Совсем забыл упомянуть, что пользователи не через Exchange работает, а к стороннему почтовику через imap подключены

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый человек поделился скриптом на powershell, можно редактировать как угодно: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/c3162ef8-cb43-4752-ba73-11261490893e/outlook-?forum=msoclientru